# HTML/CSS two background colors and centered text in table td

Tags: css, text, colors, background, html-table

I have a table, where one `<td>` with text should be two-coloured. After some research, I found a method with 4 `<div>` elements, but it doesn't look exactly like the other fields.

```
<iframe width="100%" height="300" src="http://jsfiddle.net/tG5n3/embedded/" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

The `<div>`-Method:

```
<td style="width: 90px;">
    <div style="position: relative; height: 24px;">
         <div style="position: relative; z-index: 1; top: 20%;">Action 3.1</div>
         <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; background: lightgreen; width: 50%;"></div>
         <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; background: white; width: 50%;"></div>
    </div>
</td>
```

So is there a way to handle this problem better or proper?

Here is the full code example: http://jsfiddle.net/tG5n3/

Comment: can you post the screen shot of your desired result....

Comment: do you know about the CSS3 background gradient property ? It's possible with it. The only disadvantage is that a lot browsers, especially IE below 9 doesn't support it.

Comment: screenshot of your required scenario?

Comment: I need to support at least IE 7 with this code. @ShailenderArora : I want the `<td>` to look exactly as the above cells, but with a two coloured background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **`gradient`** property to do this:

```
td.two-color {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #1EBFE1 0%, #1EBFE1 50%, #34D12C 50%, #34D12C 100%);
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(left, #1EBFE1 0%, #1EBFE1 50%, #34D12C 50%, #34D12C 100%);
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(left, #1EBFE1 0%, #1EBFE1 50%, #34D12C 50%, #34D12C 100%);
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(left, #1EBFE1 0%, #1EBFE1 50%, #34D12C 50%, #34D12C 100%);
    background-image:         linear-gradient(left, #1EBFE1 0%, #1EBFE1 50%, #34D12C 50%, #34D12C 100%);
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/metacode/Ybwzz/)

[**Demo with half white**](http://jsfiddle.net/metacode/Ybwzz/1/)

Comment: Actually, the `gradient`-property is incredible. But i need the backwards compatibility to at minimum IE 7 and comparable other versions of common browsers.